# Query data without key (AWS DynamoDB SDK Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I just got started into using AWS Nodejs SDK For DynamoDb

I"m a little confused on how I can access a specific data without using the partition key.

Let's just assume I only have 1 item in my table with the Attribute "id" set up as my partition key

**Table Name: Users**

```
{
  "full_name": {
    "S": "John Cena"
  },
  "id": {
    "S": "ABC123"
  },
  "password": {
    "S": "youcantseeme"
  },
  "username": {
    "S": "AndHisNameIs"
  }
}
```

The code below would return the object above me if I query using my key

Btw I'm using **dynamodb.query(params, function(err,data){}**

**Using Key to search**

```
let params = {
    TableName : "Users",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#myid = :id",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
        "#myid": "id"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":id": {
            S: "ABC123"
        }
    }
};
```

**Searching without the key**

-I would like it if I can access that data without specifying the id string. For example If a user sends in a "username" and "password" I wouldn't have the ID so I wouldn't be able to look for it.

-The code below would return an error stating that I'm missing a partition key "id"

```
let params = {
    TableName : "Users",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
        "#myusername": "username"
    },
    KeyConditionExpression: "#myusername = :username",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":username": {
            S: "AndHisNameIs"
        }
    }
};
```

**My work around?**

-replace the partition key with username instead of id? Is this how nosql databases work? I'm coming from a mysql environment so I was just able to just search a specific string or num or boolean by just asking for it in a certain column lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [Global Secondary Index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) to the field you want to query on. Or do a full table Scan.

Comment: If you can clear up something for me. I read the doc and it said to include the index name. Would that in my case "username"? Or was that something I needed to set up when the table is first created.

Comment: The index name is the name you give the Global Secondary Index when you create it. If you haven't created the GSI yet, then you obviously can't query on it yet. Once you create it, you will have to give it a name, and that's the name you will use. If you forgot the name you gave the GSI, you can view it in the DynamoDB console by going to the table and viewing the GSI under the "indexes" tab.

Comment: Thank you that was the answer to my problem!